# Embed a custom View inside a WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom View that I would like to "embed" in an WebView.

By embed I mean:

- The custom view intercepts onTouch events on its area
- The custom view looks like a piece of the web page, so it scrolls with the surrounding text

I wrote the custom View, so I can edit it as needed

Comment: just put it in the XML with a reference to the XML file for the custom view.
for more information: [http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Comment: This would work if my custom view were to remain fixed, but I want it to scroll with the WebView content

Comment: in that case you don't want to embed it in the view, but in the source. maybe you can do something in JS or HTML

Comment: If I could do it in JS I would, but the custom view is quite complex. I could try catching the events using JS and then actually implement them wrapping the custom view, but I don't know what the overhead would be... or how to do it.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do what you want. maybe you can use `<ScrollView><WebView1><customView><WebView2>`

Comment: @thepoosh if you put it into an answer I'll accept you :)

Comment: @miniBill: did it work?

Comment: In the end I hadn't got time to try it then, but I did something similar in another project and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said in my comment.

I can't think of a normal way to what you do. What I would do if I were you is to put the custom view in between 2 `WebView` objects like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1
     ...
     />

    <include android:layout="custom_layout" />

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView2
    ...
    />

  </ ScrollView>
```

Comment: scroll view can have one child only

Comment: I think you're talking about Flutter, Android scrollview extends FrameLayout which means there is no problem in adding multiple views to it

Answer (score 1):

Take a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as Parent. then Put WebView as First Child Layout and then your CustomView as second child view.

After this put some code to show and hide the CustomView on some specific Action.

It will surly help you.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: This won't help with making the custom view scroll with the webview